# Loading Resources in the Background with a loading scene in andEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing a game using andEngine. How do i show loading progress instead of black screen when game is getting loaded with resources.?

Comment: Hi. @Andy did u find any solution? tell if u have any.. i am also searching like this.

Comment: Refer this link :http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/very-simple-splash-screen-alternative-t5790.html